# Read source code from tabs in IE/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: c#, .net

Using C# and any .NET version I'd like to create a program that can read the source code from any open tab using IE, Firefox or Chrome. This is a program that I use for just myself. I haven't been able to find any useful information by Googling this subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the question. Is this to be a plug-in stand alone app? How do you need to interface? Very vague question.

Comment: When I log in to my bank I had to type in my account number and then they provide me with a 4 character code to which I have a key card that tells me what each letter in the code maps to. THIS IS ANNOYING. I have a C# app that I open, punch in the code and then get my magic password to login. I want to get to the point in the login where I get the 4 character code, open my app, it detects the open browsers and goes through each tab looking for the correct page, finds the 4 character code and spits out my magic password. I just want a standalone app (.exe) file I can launch from my taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a bit overkill for using C#. I'd do it using javascript and a bookmarklet, by loading the url and displaying it in an overlay on the page... especially if it's only for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to read "source code" (by this, I assume you mean the HTML source), you could write an app that uses the System.Net.WebClient class, then use the DownloadString() method to pull the source into a string and do whatever you want with it. i.e.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://your.url.here/");
```

If you're really looking to integrate with various browsers and try to see what tabs are open, I wouldn't even know where to begin with that one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want to do using a C# program you would need some kind of library to automate the browser. This is possible with IE using [WATIN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/index.html), which is really a testing library, but can do this sort of thing. For example,

```
using WatiN.Core;
...
foreach (IE ie in IE.InternetExplorers())
{
   Console.Out.WriteLine(ie.Html);
}
```

This code snippet is IE specific but version 2.0 (in beta) also works with Firefox. The roadmap does mention support for Chrome but I don't think its implemented yet.

You could also try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), another testing library. It supports all the major browsers though it may be a little more complicated to set up.